# How to improve the performance WPS vec:Clip with srsName in wfs:Query?

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver, wps

I need to export a shape in .zip file with a no native CRS. With the WPS vec:Clip call, the response time is 2.5 minutes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
  <ows:Identifier>vec:Clip</ows:Identifier>
  <wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>features</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Reference mimeType="text/xml" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wfs" method="POST">
        <wps:Body>
          <wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.0.0" outputFormat="GML2">
            <wfs:Query srsName="EPSG:3857" typeName="rv:c0506111_ccs2007splus"/>
          </wfs:GetFeature>
        </wps:Body>
      </wps:Reference>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>clip</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Data>
        <wps:ComplexData mimeType="application/json"><![CDATA[{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[1342724.8071,5836286.1877],[1342718.4154,5836243.9089],[1342716.2899,5836177.9661],[1342712.3319,5836069.7865],[1342697.1044,5835958.9979],[1342715.8319,5835928.4304],[1342748.7523,5835867.138]]]]}]]></wps:ComplexData>
      </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
  </wps:DataInputs>
  <wps:ResponseForm>
    <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="application/zip">
      <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
    </wps:RawDataOutput>
  </wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>
```

Is there a way to get the same result with greater speed?

Comment: what projection is your data stored in? how big is your dataset? how is your dataset stored?

Comment: My data stored in EPSG:3003. I want a shape with a dynamic CRS passed in input. The same operation with native CRS is performed in 3 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

The obvious way to speed this up is to add a bounding box to the WFS request, so something like:

```
<ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
 <ogc:BBOX>
  <gml:Box xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:3785">
      <gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">
        1342697.104400, 5835867.138000,1342748.752300, 5836286.187700
      </gml:coordinates>
    </gml:Box>
  </ogc:BBOX>
</ogc:Filter>
```

added to your query should help. In an ideal world GeoServer could then hand this off to your database to speed up the query using the spatial index you have on your dataset.